# How to convert hex string/bytes to ASCII characters

Tags: taquito, string

Using Taquito I can load the storage from a smart contract. This storage contains a `map` called `token_info`. If I call `token_info.get('symbol')`, I get a hex string of `"4d494e"`. How do I convert this hex string to the ASCII string "`MIN`"?

I would prefer doing this conversion using the Taquito JavaScript library.

Answer (score 3):

The `bytes2Char` function from the `@taquito/utils` package will convert these bytes to a string. The `char2bytes` is the counterpart that does the reverse.